# How to get filter result in the order of query list in Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, django-filter

I have documents something like this in my mongodb

```
{'id':1, 'url': www.aaa.com},{'id':3, 'url': www.ccc.com},{'id':2, 'url': www.bbb.com}

Model.Objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3])
```

I want result for above Django query as

```
[Model:aaa.com>,Model:bbb.com>,Model:ccc.com>]
```

All that I mean is,How to get the result in the order of the given list in the filter query .ie id=1, id=2, id=3

I didnt get result ordered always.This only sample documents.

Comment: using order_by("id") doesn't do the trick?

Comment: @GabrielAmram no,it didnt get needed result when id is something like "1003nnf",5000eeg".Here assume id has no order.Then how did i get it?

Answer (score -1):

By default, Queryset are not ordered unless you state an `order_by`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api

try `Model.Objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3]).order_by("id")`

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the built in `order_by` only allows you to order by a column in the table in ascending or descending order. If you want to customize the order, you'll need to write you own [sorting](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) function.

Comment: It can sort as we want by treated like a list.But it cannot then convert to a queryset again.